# Programmatically set App Pool identity to Domain user

Tags: c#, security, authentication, iis-7

I have a minor problem, we have an IIS application but due to some draconian security settings by the development house they cannot use IIS integrated identity as all Local accounts have been denied access to local hard drives, networking and such. As such developers need to go into advanced settings and set their domain name and password as the authentication method for the sites, folders and app pools.

I have been looking at possibly automating this so that instead of going into the system selecting each app pool, advanced settings, connect as typing in the domain name, password and set on all the pools, I want them to be able to enter their credentials into an app, which would then systematically update all the credentials to match, I can see that it is possible but none of the examples show how to get the Domain credentials etc or whether there is a simple way to set it using the "current logged in user" so that all we would need to do is get the machines to run this program at login to set the authentication every time so any password change on the domain is reflected in the local IIS settings.

I guess I can get the CurrentUser info and then use LookupAccountSid to get the SID, but how to replicate the configuration part? Where you click Set User then type in your domain name and password?

This appears to be possible but there is no information available as to how to actually perform this. I think this picture will show what I mean:

[image: The Set Credentials box I want to set programatically]

Comment: how about [impersonation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306158/how-to-implement-impersonation-in-an-asp-net-application#2)?

Comment: I've used [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager) to programmatically change the root folder of an application. It has an `ApplicationPools` property that looks very promising.

Answer (score 0):

> Where you click Set User then type in your domain name and password?
>   This appears to be possible but there is no information available as to how to actually perform this. Can anyone show a solution for this?

According to your description, I guess you want to use  impersonation to achieve your requirement.

As far as I know, the application pool identity could use the login in user's perission to access the folder by using impersonation.

The impersonation support using Specific user or Authenticated user. Authenticated user means using current login in user as the application pool identity perission. For example, you could enable the windows auth, and it will use current login in user as the application pool identity.

If you want to enable the impersonation, I suggest you could enable the windows authentication firstly.

Then you could follow below config in the web.config.

1.Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7). For information about navigating to locations in the UI, see Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).

2.In Features View, double-click Authentication.

3.On the Authentication page, select ASP.NET Impersonation.

4.In the Actions pane, click Enable to use ASP.NET Impersonation authentication with the default settings.

5.Optionally, in the Actions pane, click Edit to set the security principal.

6.In the Edit ASP.NET Impersonation Settings dialog box, select either Specific user or Authenticated user. Whichever you decide, IIS uses this identity for the security context of the ASP.NET application. By default, IIS 7 is set to impersonate the authenticated user.

7.Click OK to finish or proceed to the next optional steps to change the identity to impersonate.

8.Optionally, click Set to change the Specific user identity.

9.In the Set Credentials dialog box, enter the name of an existing user account in User name, the password associated with that user account in Password, and then the exact same value in Confirm password for a new account IIS should use for anonymous access.

You could also using below command to achieve your requirment.

Using authenticated user:

```
appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT/section:identity /impersonate:true | false
```

Using specific user

```
appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT/section:identity /userName:**string **/password:**string
```

Comment: the problem is that iisusr has been denied access to do anything so we have to use fixed identity for the whole of iis as your own domain login, the problem is when the 90 day password change comes round it forces you to manually remember every service and app pool you need to change or have your login locked out due to too many failed login attempts